# Envoy and connecting via ssh with username with capitals

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I recently installed laravel envoy task runner, when I try to run a task with command envoy run deploy I get the following error:

```
GabotronES@gabriel-ubuntu-1:/var/www/dtcburger.es$ envoy run deploy
Are you sure you want to run the [echo] task? [y/N]: y
[GabotronES:206.189.X.XX]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname gabotrones:206.189.X.XX: Name or service not known
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

It says it can't resolve hostname gabotrones but my ubuntu user is GabotronES, in my Envoy.blade.php I have also user GabotronES in @servers directive, is this because envoy doesn't allow username with capitals to connect via ssh?

```
@servers(['web' => 'GabotronES:206.189.X.XX'])
```

*censored my IP just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the capitals are the issue.

Please try this syntax:

```
@servers(['web' => 'GabotronES@206.189.X.XX'])
```

You can also try to connect directly from the command line, to check if things work as expected.